# SwarmID in Portainer API

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, portainer

[Portainer API](https://documentation.portainer.io/archive/1.23.2/API/) has this endpoint `https://{portainer_url}/api/stacks/{id}`

that returns pattern (using response from example)

```
{
  "Id": "myStack_jpofkc0i9uo9wtx1zesuk649w",
  "Name": "myStack",
  "Type": 1,
  "EndpointID": 1,
  "EntryPoint": "docker-compose.yml",
  "SwarmID": "jpofkc0i9uo9wtx1zesuk649w",
  "ProjectPath": "/data/compose/myStack_jpofkc0i9uo9wtx1zesuk649w",
  "Env": [
    {
      "name": "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD",
      "value": "password"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to get node url by using "SwarmID" returned from response.

But checking with SwarmID returns from `docker node ls`, there are no matches SwarmID given by response.

I'm wondering what is exactly SwarmID returns by Portainer? or any other ways could help me get the node that a particular stack deployed to?

Comment: Which exactly API is this? It's not SwaggerHub's own API, just something hosted there.

Comment: @Helen I might be wrong about API name. Not really sure how to correctly tell the name but here's the doc https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/deviantony/Portainer/1.23.2/

Comment: It's Portainer API - the docs (https://documentation.portainer.io/archive/1.23.2/API/) may have more info. Or consider contacting their support for assistance.

Answer (score 4):

SwarmID can be viewed after the swarm is initialized, use the docker info command in manager node, as [we can see in docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/info/):

```
$ docker info
<...>
ClusterID: 9vs5ygs0gguyyec4iqf2314c0
Managers: 1
Nodes: 1
Data Path Port: 7777
<...>
```

This **clusterId** corresponds to the **swarmId** requested in the portainer api when you need to create a stack: https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/deviantony/Portainer/1.23.2/#/stacks/StackCreate

You can do a GET request to docker info through portainer api:

```
request({
        url: PORTAINER_URL + '/api/endpoints/' + ENDPOINT_ID + '/docker/info',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': ' application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + bearer
        }
    }, function (error, response, body) {...});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).